# Why does ZipInputStream.getNextEntry() return null?

Tags: java, zipinputstream

I have a zip file that is AES encrypted.  After decrypting I'm left with a byte[] containing the zip content.  But when I try to unzip it, using a ByteArrayInputStream, ZipInputStream.getNextEntry() returns null right away.  Debugging, I see that my byte[] doesn't have a required local file header signature which is

static long LOCSIG = 0x04034b50L;   // "PK\003\004"

so ZipInputStream.getNextEntry() returns null.

If, however, I write those decrypted bytes out to a file and then use a FileInputStream() that I pass to ZipInputStream(), everything works as expected.  Below is my current code.  Can anyone suggest a way to unzip without first writing out to a temporary file?

```
    byte[] data = AESUtil.decryptInputStream(...);
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(bis);
    ZipEntry entry;
    while ((entry = stream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Use a [CipherInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html).

Comment: The same thing happens when I use a CipherInputStream.  The ZipInputStream.readLOC() returns null on this comparison:
**
       if (get32(tmpbuf, 0) != LOCSIG) {
            return null;
        }
**

Comment: I need to correct my initial post - and apologize: I incorrectly wrote that if I write the decrypted bytes out to a file and then use FileInputStream with the ZipInputStream everything works.  I didn't actually try that - I simply ran the UNIX command "unzip" on the decrypted file and that worked.  I just assumed - incorrectly - that FileInputStream/ZipInputStream would work if that were the case.

So, in summary, it looks like I'm writing out a decrypted zip file with bytes that the "zip" program can handle, but ZipInputStream cannot.

Comment: I should clarify:  use CipherInputStream instead of a ByteArrayOutputStream.  I suspect the problem may lie in your AWSUtil.decryptInputStream method.  So just use `new ZipInputStream(new CipherInputStream(originalInputStream, cipher))`.

Comment: @VGR I understood your original post.  I was doing exactly what you specified in your subsequent clarification.  But I still got the same result - the ZipInputStream.getnextEntry() returns null because the first 32 bytes of the byte stream don't match some expected header value of 0x04034b50L.  But the standalone "unzip" program unzips a file with the same exact bytes just fine.  I think I might need to try another library (isn't there an apache commons zip/unzip lib?)

Comment: `unzip` is known to be highly tolerant of extra bytes at the start and/or end of the file.  I suspect the java.util.zip API isn’t as tolerant.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to the conclusion that ZipInputStream just isn't flexible enough.  When I substituted the above code with Apache Commons' compress classes, everything works.  Below is a working implementation using that library and the same byte array:

```
byte[] data = AESUtil.decryptInputStream(...);
SeekableInMemoryByteChannel inMemoryByteChannel = new SeekableInMemoryByteChannel(data);
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(inMemoryByteChannel);
Iterator<ZipArchiveEntry> iterator = = zipFile.getEntriesInPhysicalOrder().asIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    ...
}
```